# Notepad ++ How to delete new line after a specific character?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to remove the new line of every line starting with the character `>`

I have the following text:

```
a
> b
> c
d
```

The output should be:

```
abc
d
```

Comment: Can't understand the question, could you give a proper example and elaborate it?

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear what you want to replace. I cannot see where the character '>' is set in your example. do you mean tabulation ?

Comment: @A.Joly I edited the text just now. It seems the character > is automatically replaced by a new line.

Comment: So whenever there is character '>', you want to remove it and merge that line to end of the previous line. Is it what you want?

Comment: @LightYagami yes that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

[image]

In the *Replace* field add `\r\n>*press spacebar*` and in the *Replace with* field - leave it blank. Dont forget to tick in Search mode the Extended mode.

**Explanation:**

If you write your text out and go View -> Show Symbol -> Show all characters, it will look like this on Windows:

[image]

CR is a bytecode for carriage return (from the days of typewriters) and LF similarly, for line feed. So essentially what you want to do is remove the carriage return + new line + the > symbol and the next *space* symbol combination if it is present in your text. For this, enable the Extended search mode: CR is represented as `\r`, new line - as `\n`, others are self-explanatory.

Comment: That's great! Thank you